# How to draw text around circle arcs in Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to draw text right above each arc. All 6 arcs together create a full circle. The below code works perfectly when I uncomment the line `draw_circle([60,60,60,60,60,59])` , but the text position gets wrong when I run the line `draw_circle([120,60,60,60,30,29])`

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

def draw(start_angle, new_angle, text):
    x = math.cos(math.radians(start_angle +new_angle/2)) * 190 + 200
    y = math.sin(math.radians(start_angle +new_angle/2)) * 190 + 200

    canvas.create_arc((20,20,380,380), activedash=(50,10), fill='lightblue', outline="white", start=start_angle, extent=new_angle, tag="pie"+str(x)+"_"+str(y))
    txt = canvas.create_text(1, 1, text=text, fill="red")
    canvas.itemconfig(txt)
    canvas.coords(txt, x, y)
    print(f"start_angle:{start_angle}, new_angle:{new_angle}, x:{x}, y:{y}")
    return txt
   
def draw_circle(angle_list):
    start_angle=0
    for new_angle in angle_list:
        draw(start_angle, new_angle,str(new_angle))
        start_angle+=new_angle

# draw_circle([60,60,60,60,60,59])
draw_circle([120,60,60,60,30,29])

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is math related and a full circle has 360.

```
x = math.cos(math.radians(start_angle +new_angle/2)) * 190 + 200
y = math.sin(math.radians(start_angle +new_angle/2)) * 190 + 200
```

should be changed to this:

```
x = math.cos(math.radians(-(start_angle +new_angle/2))) * 190 + 200    #minus angle
y = math.sin(math.radians(-(start_angle +new_angle/2))) * 190 + 200    #minus angle
```

.

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

def draw(start_angle, new_angle, text):
    x = math.cos(math.radians(-(start_angle +new_angle/2))) * 190 + 200    #minus angle
    y = math.sin(math.radians(-(start_angle +new_angle/2))) * 190 + 200    #minus angle

    canvas.create_arc((20,20,380,380), activedash=(50,10), fill='lightblue', outline="white", start=start_angle, extent=new_angle, tag="pie"+str(x)+"_"+str(y))
    txt = canvas.create_text(1, 1, text=text, fill="red")
    canvas.itemconfig(txt)
    canvas.coords(txt, x, y)
    print(f"start_angle:{start_angle}, new_angle:{new_angle}, x:{x}, y:{y}")
    return txt
   
def draw_circle(angle_list):
    start_angle=0
    for new_angle in angle_list:
        draw(start_angle, new_angle,str(new_angle))
        start_angle+=new_angle

# draw_circle([60,60,60,60,60,59])
draw_circle([120,60,60,60,30,29])

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you consider sharing a link to some literature where I can understand the basic concept of the Math you mentioned where the negative angle is used?

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinate system of a canvas has a reversed y-axis, you need to minus the calculated y distance from 200 instead:

```py
y = 200 - math.sin(math.radians(start_angle+new_angle/2)) * 190
```